# How can i Tlit the layout from Left to Right?

Tags: android, android-layout, animation

I want to know about the Layout which can be Tlit from Left to Right. please give me any suggestion for help out me.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&sa=X&ei=6SXfT9SNEYK3rAf51cy0DQ&ved=0CAYQvwUoAQ&q=gesture+detection+and+viewflipper+android+example&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=58d94699afce0bb0&biw=1366&bih=682

Answer (score 0):

You can create .xml layouts for when the phone is placed horizontal or vertical. To create a horizontal layout, simply create a new .xml file and check that you would like the layout to be horizontal.